# stopping excel from updating formula after a criteria is matched

Tags: excel, vba

Hi i need help with stopping excel from updating formula after a criteria is matched.
I have the following:

Cell A1 is =TODAY() Cell

B1 is Date Received

Cell C1 is Number of days open.(contains the formula)
This obtained by the following formula:

=IF(B1="","-",IF(NETWORKDAYS($B1,$A$1)>0,NETWORKDAYS($C1,$A$1),"-"))

This returns the number of days a sales quote has been open.

The second part is once the invoice has been done and now I have a second date to use.

Cell D1 is Date the invoice is completed
Cell E1 is number of days taken to invoice(contains the formula)

This is obtained by the following formula:

=IF(NETWORKDAYS($B1,$D1)>0, NETWORKDAYS($B1,$D1),"-")

What I need is once Cell D1 is filled out that Excell freezes Cell C1 and not continue counting days between B1 and A1 as cell A1 will update each new day?
Can this be done and how if so?

Comment: Format your code properly, it's very difficult to understand the way it is posted.

Comment: Fr0zenFyr can i send you sample of the sheet to look at?

Comment: I'm afraid that won't be of much use. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for more help on formatting your posts. See [asking help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to know how to ask questions to get most attention and possibly best solutions.

Comment: `C1` contains the formula `=IF(C1="","-",IF(NETWORKDAYS($C1,$A$1)>0,NETWORKDAYS($C1,$A$1),"-")) ` which has a circular reference, or should those references be to `$B1`?

Comment: Hi Darren could i send you a copy of the sheet to see the formula in context?

Comment: Sorry, must've forgotten this comment.  No, sorry.  Should the `Networkdays` formula be referencing `C1` if it's pasted in `C1`.   I'd suggest that once you have a value in cell `D1` you use that rather than the `TODAY()` value. Also decide which question you want to stay - this one or [the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49485811/formula-in-excel-query)