# Formula in Excel query

Tags: excel, vba

I need help with stopping Excel from updating formula after a criteria is matched. I have the following:

- Cell A1 is `=TODAY()` cell
- B1 is "Date Received"

Cell C1 is number of days open (contains the formula). This value is obtained by the following formula:

```
=IF(B1="","-",IF(NETWORKDAYS($B1,$A$1)>0,NETWORKDAYS($C1,$A$1),"-"))
```

This returns the number of days a sales quote has been open.

The second part is once the invoice has been done and now I have a second date to use.

Cell D1 is Date the invoice is completed Cell E1 is number of days taken to invoice (contains the formula)

This is obtained by the following formula:

```
=IF(NETWORKDAYS($B1,$D1)>0, NETWORKDAYS($B1,$D1),"-")
```

What I need is once Cell D1 is filled out that Excel freezes Cell C1 and not continue counting days between B1 and A1 as cell A1 will update each new day? Can this be done and how if so?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [stopping excel from updating formula after a criteria is matched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49427351/stopping-excel-from-updating-formula-after-a-criteria-is-matched)

Comment: @D Beech Instead of opening a duplicate question, you should edit your previously existing question. Editing a question will bring it back towards the top of the active questions list.